# Does $g'$ need to be continuous for $g(x_0) = 0$, $g'(x_0) \neq 0$ to imply $g$ changes sign in a neighborhood of $x_0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

The following theorem holds:

**Theorem:** Let $g:\mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable and let $x_0 \in \mathcal{A} $. If $g(x_0)=0, \; g'(x_0)\neq 0$ then $g$ changes sign at a neighbourhood of $x_0$.

**Questions:**

1. Do we need $g'$ to be continous on the interval $\mathcal{A}$?
2. If yes, then give a counter example of a $g$ function that satisfies all the hypothesis but not the conclusion.

*I suspect that $g'$ should be continous, although I cannot find a counter example. I know a proof of the theorem which come from MVT (mean value theorem) and Taylor , but I don't know if we do need $g'$ to be continuous.*

Comment: No. Take $x_0=0$ and $c=g'(0)>0$. From the definition of derivative, it follows that for small $h$, $f(h)/h>c/2$. This implies $f(h)>0$ for small positive $h$ and $f(h)<0$ for small negative $h$.

Comment: You mean that $g'$ should not necessarily be continuous.. right? Or I misunderstood something?

Comment: I meant the answer to 1. is "no".

Comment: Good.. ok.. thanks.. I just saw the answer now below.. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $g$ does not change sign. Then either $x_0$ is local minimum or a local maximum point. Hence $g'(x_0)=0$.